# Windows Security Descriptor Inquiry

Tags: windows, security

I'd like to dissect what this security descriptor permits and/or denies, I am not 100% sure myself outside of administrative groups. TIA!

D:(A;OICI;GA;;;BA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is all defined in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/ace-strings). You have a DACL with 1 ACE.

ACE:

- Allow
- Flags: OBJECT_INHERIT, CONTAINER_INHERIT
- Access rights: GENERIC_ALL
- Identity: BUILTIN\Administrators

GENERIC_ALL is a generic access that is mapped to a specific set of rights once the type of object is known.